# Using BigQuery repeated / nested fields in Power BI

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi

**Problem:** When connecting Power BI to a BigQuery table (using the native BQ connector) with repeated / nested fields, these fields do not appear in Power BI for use in report creation.

**Example:** Using a Public BigQuery data set called bigquery-public-data:samples, there is a table called github_nested which has repeated fields such as payload.pages.action (see below)

[image: BigQuery repeated / nested fields]

However, when connecting to this BigQuery table using Power BI I only get a handful of fields (see below)

[image: Power BI Report canvas]

As I understand, this is because the Power BI Big Query connector doesn't support repeated / nested or record fields.

**Question:** Is there any workaround to have all columns / fields in a BigQuery table (regardless of whether they are repeated / nested / records) available for use when building Power BI reports, specifically using a live connection over the native Power BI Big Query connector?

I do have write permissions in BigQuery so creating views on top of these tables with repeated / nested fields is possible if required as part of a solution.

One potential workaround might be to create a view in Big Query which un-nests repeated fields and then connect Power BI to said view. Open to any workaround suggestions.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It seems like this is not supported, There is a FR [here](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Issues/BigQuery-connector-no-support-for-nested-data/idi-p/246858) but didn't gain much traction so far.

Comment: Thanks @GuillemXercavins.

Yes, I've also read that the Power BI BigQuery connector doesn't support repeated / nested columns, however, I'm wondering if there are any workaround which might enable reporting off of these columns? For example, one idea might be to create a view in Big Query which un-nests repeated fields and then connect Power BI to said view.

Open to any workaround suggestions.

Comment: Yes, that might be the best option

Comment: Thanks @GuillemXercavins, however I'm not sure exactly how to do this or if this is indeed the best approach. This is why I have asked the questions, to see if anyone might have successfully done this before or if someone with more knowledge of BigQuery than myself might be able to assist.

Answer (score 2):

Power BI does not have (as of 29/10/2018) a native Big Query connector, it just uses a generic ODBC connector. I would advise not to use it for production, current limitations are :

- GCP billing accounts are not supported if your billing project is different than your dataset project
- Google Service Accounts are not supported
- Nested and repeated fields are not supported
- Requests are not optimized (bad finops)
- Dataset linked to Google Sheets through Big Query are not supported
- Some data types are not correctly handled
- Requests cannot be manually edited (using BQ Standard SQL for exemple)

Learn more in this article (i am the author): https://medium.com/@remy_david/which-bi-tool-for-big-query-d9eb838ff7ad

Answer (score 0):

Example schema of `products-and-stocks` table:

```json
[
  {
    name: 'timestamp',
    type: 'TIMESTAMP'
  }, {
    name: 'data',
    type: 'RECORD',
    mode: "REPEATED",
    fields: [
      {
        name: 'itemId',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'prodId',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'name',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'stockA',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'stockB',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'stockQ',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'stockD',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'stockE',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'weight',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'size',
        type: 'RECORD',
        fields: [
          {
            name: 'length',
            type: 'INTEGER'
          }, {
            name: 'width',
            type: 'INTEGER'
          }, {
            name: 'height',
            type: 'INTEGER'
          }
        ]
      }, {
        name: 'cnt',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'cntInBox',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'lifetime',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'barcode',
        type: 'STRING',
        mode: 'REPEATED',
      }, {
        name: 'dateStockUpdate',
        type: 'TIMESTAMP'
      }, {
        name: 'label',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'comment',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'commentPack',
        type: 'STRING'
      }, {
        name: 'skuBox',
        type: 'INTEGER'
      }, {
        name: 'snRuleRegularExpression',
        type: 'STRING'
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Create flattening query in the BigQuery and save it as a View.

```sql
SELECT 
  `timestamp`, 
  repeated.*, 
  repeated.size.length as `size_length`, 
  repeated.size.width as `size_width`, 
  repeated.size.height as `size_height`, 
  ARRAY_TO_STRING(barcode, ", ") as barcodesFlat 
FROM 
  `my-project-id.my-dataset.products-and-stocks`
CROSS JOIN UNNEST(`data`) as repeated
```

Import this view into Power BI.